Не запускается Flask приложение
имеем самый простой в мире код на фласк(из стандартной документации):
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

# This is a mongodb database
db = client.flask_database
# This is a todos collection
todos = db.todos

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run(debug=True)



При запуске, казалось бы, все работает. Никаких ошибок не выдает. Но и ничего полезного тоже не происходит: терминал просто думает секунду-другую, и закрывается. Как пофиксить можно ?

Заранее запустите терминал и запускайте этот код через заранее запущенный терминал, чтобы он не закрывался и вы смогли прочитать текст ошибки

В конце кода вместо if __name__ == 'main': нужно написать if (__name__ == '__main__'):
Вот исправленый код:
from flask import Flask
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

# This is a mongodb database
db = client.flask_database
# This is a todos collection
todos = db.todos

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)

